# how to enable basic auth in aws s3 without using cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a S3 bucket and here I have some Image files. any one who have download link in the world can download that files.

But, I want to restrict it using basic username and password authentication. without using cloudfront way. is any alternative ways available in aws? to enable basic auth before download.

Comment: it's not exactly what you want, but would presigned urls do the job for you?

Comment: Amazon S3 does not support basic authentication (username, password). Instead, you can use AWS credentials when calling Amazon S3 APIs. These can be permanent credentials (from IAM Users) or temporary credentials (from AWS Security Token Service). Or, there is also an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. However these types of temporary credentials require a 'back-end' to generate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using S3 Bucket Policy with custom header like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "getwithauthen",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*.txt",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": "username",
                    "aws:Referer": "password"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "allowgetwithoutauthen",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*.pem"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then I get the content of txt files by using curl command:

```
curl --user-agent username --referer password --request GET "https://s3-url"
```

But I haven't tested with images yet. I think you can use curl -O to get the images

Comment: it's working for images too. is any other way when user click a link ask them to enter username and password before download. alternative for cloudfront approach.

Comment: I think you will need a web application for that feature

Comment: Or you can create IAM role, make people assume role to download the file. 
Btw, if my answer help you, please mark it as acceptance

Comment: This is [Security through obscurity - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) (which is never a good idea), but I must say it's quite a clever hack!

Comment: I know @JohnRotenstein. First of all, this s3 is only for developer to get txt file. But one day, a developer raise to manager that the bucket is not secured. And then we turn a simple click-and-download link into an API.